# How to compile Java files that put .class files directly into JAR

Tags: java, jar, javac

First some reference:
[1st Link](http://dan.bodar.com/2012/02/28/crazy-fast-build-times-or-when-10-seconds-starts-to-make-you-nervous/)
[2nd link](http://www.jpountz.net/projects/Parallel-Ant)

The first article [1st Link](http://dan.bodar.com/2012/02/28/crazy-fast-build-times-or-when-10-seconds-starts-to-make-you-nervous/)  mentions about compiling the Java files directly into JAR files and avoiding one step in the build process. Does anyone know this?

-Vadiraj

Comment: I think you misunderstood. The article says, "Always compile and jar in one step" i.e. compile classes, jar them up and then run your tests using the jar to reduce IO. It does not say anything about compiling files straight into a jar.

Comment: @dogbane - you should put that in an answer

Comment: .. but when I read this line from the first [1] reference "(the java compiler supports writing directly to jars but it’s not used for some reason)", I am confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the author is talking about extending the compiler itself, it is possible that he has knowledge of the built-in capabilities of the compiler (that is what the compiler is capable of, maybe with a little encouragement by tweaking the code).

> Right now I’m investigating *extending the Java 6 compiler* to remove the unneeded file exists checks and possible jaring the class files directly in the compiler. [emphasis mine]

That capability, however, is certainly not supported officially (no documentation exist about it on the [javac webpage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)).

At best, the feature is compiler dependent; possibly requiring modification of the compiler's source code.

Answer (score 3):

As you linked to my blog post I thought it was only fair to give you an update.

Compiling directly to a Jar is actually fairly simple to do. Basically you extend

```
javax.tools.ForwardingJavaFileObject
```

Then override `openOutputStream` method and direct it to your Jar. As the Java Compiler is highly concurrent but writing to a jar file is highly sequential I'd recommend that you buffer to byte arrays and then have a background thread that writes the byte arrays as they arrive.

I do exactly this is my experimental build tool JCompilo https://code.google.com/p/jcompilo/
This tool is completely undocumented but crazy fast. Currently it's about 20-80% faster than  any other Java build tool and about 10x faster than the Scala compiler for the same code.